# Converting a java-List<T> into a stream usable with iomicrometer's MultiGauge

Tags: java, stream, grafana, prometheus, micrometer

from my springboot app i receive a list of results `List<T>` with 100 Elements read from a database table using

`T` contains the fields

- unique identifier
- longitude
- latitude
- value

i want to turn this into multiple micrometer-gauges like

```
object{id=<unique identifier>,longitude=<longitude>,latitude=<latitude>} <value>
object{id=<unique identifier>,longitude=<longitude>,latitude=<latitude>} <value>
object{id=<unique identifier>,longitude=<longitude>,latitude=<latitude>} <value>
...
```

The metrics shall be scraped by prometheus and then visualized using [grafana/worldmap](https://www.robustperception.io/using-geohashes-with-the-worldmap-panel-and-prometheus)

i am building my multi-gauge using
`MultiGauge l100 = MultiGauge.builder("metric-last100").register(registry);`

and terribly failing at converting that `List<T>` into a stream to feed `l100.register(...)` as shown [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/807#issuecomment-429111036):

```
// SELECT count(*) from job group by status WHERE job = 'dirty'     
MultiGauge statuses = MultiGauge.builder("statuses")
        .tag("job", "dirty")
        .description("The number of widgets in various statuses")
        .baseUnit("widgets")
        .register(registry);

...

// run this periodically whenever you re-run your query     
statuses.register(
  resultSet.stream().map(result -> 
    Row.of(Tags.of("status", result.getAsString("status")),     
    result.getAsInt("count")))
)
```

Here is my actual code:

```
private MultiGauge l100;
...
l100 = MultiGauge.builder("ids-metric-last100").register(registry);
...   
public void updateMetricLast100Deliveries() {
  List<C3MpGeodataDOM> last100 = c3MpGeodataDAO.getlast100();

  l100.register(
    last100.stream().map(
        res -> Row.of(
            Tags.of(
                "sdgnr", res.getMpPK().getSdgnr(),
                "latitude", "" + res.getGeo_latitude(),
                "longitude", "" + res.getGeo_longitude()),
            1)));
}
```

Please forgive me my dumbness, can someone please help?

thanks

/M

Comment: Please show how you convert the objects.

Comment: @Turing85 - i am working along the linked example - i added the code. I am trying to replace the `resultSet.stream` with my `List <T>`
I dont have any working code - thats my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

1 - Create a class to store your results and convert the data to a MultiGauge.Row

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserData {

  private String gender;
  private Long counter;

  public MultiGauge.Row<UserData> toRow() {
    return MultiGauge.Row.of(Tags.of("gender", gender), this, c -> this.counter);
  }

}
```

2 - Create a custom query to group your results

```
@Query(value = "select new multigauge.multigauge.UserData(usr.gender, count(usr.id)) " +
    "from users usr " +
    "group by usr.gender")
   List<UserData> retrieveUsersGroupedByGender();
```

3 - Convert the list using the toRow method and register your MultiGauge

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
  public void updateGauges() {
    multiGauge.register(userRepository.retrieveUsersGroupedByGender()
      .stream()
      .map(UserData::toRow)
      .collect(toList()), true);
  }
```

4 - Initialize your MultiGauge

```
@PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    multiGauge = MultiGauge.builder("users_grouped_by_gender_metric").register(prometheusMeterRegistry);
  }
```

I recommend taking a look at the unit tests from the official GitHub repo:

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/test/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MultiGaugeTest.java

Comment: I don't think that this answer adds much real value because it's just a link. Consider at least summarizing something from the post to make it more valuable for readers. Of course, please continue to cite your source and give credit where it's due. For details on link-only answers, please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/312717

Comment: I agree with you. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Can't find any of these annotations. Where they came from? What c->this.counter means?